# Trouble with WebRTC in Nightly (22) and Chrome (25)

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I'm experimenting with WebRTC between two browsers using RTCPeerConnection and my own long-polling implementation. I've created demo application, which successfully works with Mozilla Nightly (22), however in Chrome (25), I can't get no remote video and only "empty black video" appears. Is there something wrong in my JS code?

Function *sendMessage(message)* sends message to server via long-polling and on the other side, it is accepted using *onMessage()*

```
var peerConnection;
var peerConnection_config = {"iceServers": [{"url": "stun:23.21.150.121"}]};

// when message from server is received
function onMessage(evt) {

    if (!peerConnection)
        call(false);

    var signal = JSON.parse(evt);
    if (signal.sdp) {
        peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(signal.sdp));
    } else {
        peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(signal.candidate));
    }
}

function call(isCaller) {

    peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnection_config);

    // send any ice candidates to the other peer
    peerConnection.onicecandidate = function(evt) {
        sendMessage(JSON.stringify({"candidate": evt.candidate}));
    };

    // once remote stream arrives, show it in the remote video element
    peerConnection.onaddstream = function(evt) {
        // attach media stream to local video - WebRTC Wrapper
        attachMediaStream($("#remote-video").get("0"), evt.stream);
    };

    // get the local stream, show it in the local video element and send it
    getUserMedia({"audio": true, "video": true}, function(stream) {
        // attach media stream to local video - WebRTC Wrapper
        attachMediaStream($("#local-video").get("0"), stream);
        $("#local-video").get(0).muted = true;
        peerConnection.addStream(stream);

        if (isCaller)
            peerConnection.createOffer(gotDescription);
        else {
            peerConnection.createAnswer(gotDescription);
        }

        function gotDescription(desc) {
            sendMessage(JSON.stringify({"sdp": desc}));
            peerConnection.setLocalDescription(desc);

        }
    }, function() {
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm also interested in WebRTC, if you have any resources that have helped you, could you possibly share them with me, I can't find much out there at the moment.

Comment: unfortunately, it's really difficult to find some up-to-date resources, even some howto tutorial. I'll post it here if I find something.

Comment: well I'm afraid it depends on the order of connection steps, is that righ? ANd I forgot mention that for convenience I used simple adapter, so I don't have to solve the prefix differences between Chrome and Nightly

Comment: I found a very useful resource that used SignalR to send messages, and got that working. The following post helped me: http://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=182. Hopefully it can help you too. I can't see anything wrong in the code at the moment.

Comment: @pburgess Thanks for the link, I'll try it as soon as possible. As handshake messaging between browsers, I'm actually using long-polling technique provided by asynchronous Java servlet.

Comment: It shouldn't really make a difference to be honest. As long as the messages are getting through, the technique shouldn't matter. Have you tried outputting the message to the console when it's received?

Comment: Yes, and my long polling servlet works good, in both Chrome and Nightly the remote video stream was received, so I think there's no problem with messaging technique. And it works good in Nightly, but in Chrome it doesn't, maybe only once or twice, but in most cases not, that's strange

Comment: How are you trying this? Is it on the same machine, are there firewalls? I came across an interesting problem today, the messages would be sent fine, but the video stream was never received. I believe it was because a firewall was blocking the incoming or outgoing video. The stream worked fine when on the same network. There really is not much notification of this.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that there is a problem with your STUN server configuration. To determine if this is the issue, try using google's public stun server `stun:stun.l.google.com:19302` (which won't work in Firefox, but should definitely work in Chrome) or test on a local network with no STUN server configured.

Also, verify that your ice candidates are being delivered properly. Firefox doesn't actually generate 'icecandidate' events (it includes the candidates in the offer/answer), so an issue with delivering candidate messages could also explain the discrepancy.

Comment: Hello, I've tried my code without the stun server settings and the behavior was the same. In Nightly, it works properly and in Chrome, only black background on the video element appeared on the called side and the caller hasn't received any remote video stream. Anyaway, I'll try to do some another tests. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your video tag attribute autoplay is set to 'autoplay'.